# .htaccess rewriterule not working properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to mask a URL that looks like this:

http://example.com/test-test-test-test/item.swf?id=122

...to display the content of this URL, while passing on the GET parameter:

http://example.com/images/item.swf?id=122

This is because `item.swf` does not actually exist in the `test-test-test-test` directory. I'm currently using this, however it is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^test-test-test-test/item\.swf\?id=([0-9]+)$ images/item\.swf\?id=$1 [L]
```

This .htaccess file is in my root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^test-test-test-test/item\.swf /images/item.swf?id=%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Clean and concise answer, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule` regex isn't on query parameters, for this, you can use the [`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag:

"*When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query strings to be combined.*"

Example :

```
RewriteRule ^test-test-test-test/item\.swf$ images/item.swf [L,QSA]
```

Hope it helps.